# in the system vs. of the system

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference in the meaning and usage of *in the system* and *of the system*.
For instance:

*Organs in the respiratory system* and *Organs of the respiratory system*

*Components in a system* and *Components of a system*

Which one would be more appropriate if we want to talk about the functions or roles of a system?

Comment: *Books **in** a library* are located in the building. *Books **of** a library* could be borrowed and currently located at somebody's house. *In* means *located at*, and *of* means *belonging to*.

Comment: Thanks, @JasonBassford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both *in* and *of* might be used in the example sentences, they have different meanings, and it might not always be appropriate to use one over the other.

Generally, *in* means *located at*, and *of* means *belonging to*:

- Books **in** a library are located at the building.
- Books **of** a library belong to it, but might actually be located at the house of somebody who has borrowed them—or any number of other places.

---

In the same analysis, the following could be said in the case of organs and the respiratory system:

- Some of the organs **of** the cadaver's respiratory system were still located **in** its respiratory system. However, they would soon be removed for more detailed inspection, and then placed into individual storage containers.

---

Something similar could be done with components and a system, although it would depend on the nature of what's being described if a system's components could actually exist outside of the system itself or not.

In general, however, and barring a specific context that would recommend one preposition over another, [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=components%20in%20a%20system%2Ccomponents%20of%20a%20system&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomponents%20in%20a%20system%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomponents%20of%20a%20system%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccomponents%20in%20a%20system%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomponents%20of%20a%20system%3B%2Cc0) shows that *components of a system* is four times as common as *components in a system*.

[image: components in or of a system]

Comment: Thank a lot for the detailed explanation, Jason.
I did notice that _of_ is used more often, but couldn't find an explanation.
Really appreciate your help!